# Ports for Dial up connection

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ras

How to open a port or how to check whether the port is opened or not to make a dial up connection.

Does `RASDIAL.exe` checks whether the port is openend or not before starting the dial up connection?? 
What happens if the USB is unplugged when the connection is established? Does `RASDIAL` return a error value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Win Api, see *[Establishing a Dial-Up Connection to the Internet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384005.aspx)*.

Especially following functions:

- [InternetGetConnectedState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702.aspx)
- [InternetGetConnectedStateEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384705.aspx)